# How to prevent a website from sending data to foreign servers?

Tags: security, web

Let's say I am using a foreign WYSIWYG editor. How do I make sure it does not upload my images on its own server?

Comment: The `WYSIWYG editor` should be hosted on your server to prevent that. If you submit to another server you have no control.

Comment: TY for your response user3783243. In my case it is a npm module, so it is hosted on my server. But still the module can contain some scripts that I don't have control upon.

Comment: route your browser through a proxy and you may then add filters to allow traffic only to the allowed sites.. you will then know if any request gets blocked then that is what you are looking for...

Comment: TY for your answer Soumen. I can set up my browser, but how would I do for the browser of other users?